# c# to vb.net How to inherit more than one class? Can't convert it. SharpDevelop failed, too

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, sharpdevelop, c#-to-vb.net

I tried to convert this code from c# to vb.net but it always fails because vb.net does not allow to inherit more than one class into a class.

How can this be solved?

Here is the c# code:

```
 public class MyPromptService : PromptService, nsIAuthPrompt, nsIAuthPrompt2
{
   nsICancelable nsIAuthPrompt2.AsyncPromptAuth(nsIChannel aChannel, nsIAuthPromptCallback aCallback, nsISupports aContext, uint level, nsIAuthInformation authInfo)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();

    }

    bool nsIAuthPrompt2.PromptAuth(nsIChannel aChannel, uint level, nsIAuthInformation authInfo)
    {
        nsString.Set(authInfo.SetUsernameAttribute, "Username");
        nsString.Set(authInfo.SetPasswordAttribute, "Password");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks so far for your help.

Comment: sIAuthPrompt, nsIAuthPrompt2 are interfaces not class

Comment: Also C# doesn't allow to inherit more than one class. Everything same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converter ***should*** be able to infer that the 2nd and 3rd bases are interfaces (also added 'AddressOf' after further hints by op):

```
Public Class MyPromptService
    Inherits PromptService
    Implements nsIAuthPrompt, nsIAuthPrompt2

    Private Function nsIAuthPrompt2_AsyncPromptAuth(ByVal aChannel As nsIChannel, ByVal aCallback As nsIAuthPromptCallback, ByVal aContext As nsISupports, ByVal level As UInteger, ByVal authInfo As nsIAuthInformation) As nsICancelable Implements nsIAuthPrompt2.AsyncPromptAuth
       Throw New NotImplementedException()

    End Function

    Private Function nsIAuthPrompt2_PromptAuth(ByVal aChannel As nsIChannel, ByVal level As UInteger, ByVal authInfo As nsIAuthInformation) As Boolean Implements nsIAuthPrompt2.PromptAuth
        nsString.Set(AddressOf authInfo.SetUsernameAttribute, "Username")
        nsString.Set(AddressOf authInfo.SetPasswordAttribute, "Password")
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Hi,thanks so far! I already got that,but then I got a error: Argument not specified for parameter 'aPassword' of 'Sub SetPasswordAttribute(aPassword As nsAStringBase)'

Comment: It appears to be that nsString.Set takes a delegate as the first parameter - if this is true (and a converter would have no way of knowing this with your C# code snippet), change the first arguments of the nsString.Set call to "AddressOf authInfo.SetUsernameAttribute".  I've updated my answer to reflect this possibility.

Comment: Perfect, that works fine !! Thank you very very much for your help!